# How to tell if dual channel is working

Tags: ram, amd-ryzen

I got this issue:
Yesterday I built my pc with 8gb of ram on dual channel (2x4), but after the installation I realized that there was no 8gb of ram, **THERE WERE 20GB!!** The guys who I brought one of the memories gave me one of 16gb instead for accident.
Now, does this affect dual channel? I'm right now using integrated graphics so is really important this for me. How do I check out this? I can't find any software capable to tell me in a simple way. If anyone can help me, I'll be very grateful with you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You must consult the documentation for your motherboard to learn how RAM modules are supposed to be installed and to get information about what configurations are supported.

This is not something you can configure inside the operating system.

Some motherboards require RAM to be installed in specific positions if all slots are not filled.

Generally, RAM is **supposed** to be installed in **identical pairs**.  If you don't do this, your results will vary. Timings and frequencies must match exactly to run in dual channel mode. For pairs of RAM that are not identical, they can only operate as fast as the timings they have in common, which may be slower than what each could do individually.

Many manufactures also publish a Qualified Vendor List (QVL) which explicitly states all of the SKUs of RAM that your board is known to support.

Answer (score 1):

for 4gb + 16Gb it **will NOT work on dual channel**, if you have access to 20GB of RAM.

A simple explanation requires minimal understanding of how data in RAM is accessed:

each channel per slot can access 64bits. if you combine two compatible pieces of ram in dual-channel, the system will increase the size of the address to 128bits and will access 64bits in each ram simultaneously (eg. fetch position 1 in channel A and B for this ram slot simultaneously providing 128bits of data per request instead 2 requests of 64bits); the definition of address size is per slot; so, if populated correctly, you can have 8GB + 8Gb in dual-channel + 4GB in single + 8GB in single, as 2 x 8GB share the same channel.

As there is a difference in the memory size, to recognize 20Gb, it is mandatory to have different data addresses, as after 4gb, there will not equivalent position for the in the 4GB piece to its counterpart in 16GB ram, because there is no space to allocate it, hence, to allocate the extra 12GB each ram stick is independent.

All that said, if possible, I would keep the 16GB instead changing it to 4Gb. Dual channel provide faster access to RAM, it will not make you GPU go 2x faster, because GPU are optimized to process data and load data simultaneously to compensate a very high latency and probably for onboard GPU your biggest limitation is processing capability of the GPU itself, not the RAM access.

Comment: So, is it better to keep it with the 20gb of ram, or rather should I leave only the 16gb? Or it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: keep the 20gb. For sure you will have a better performance than 16GB only.

Answer (score 0):

Dual-channel as long as i know is a configuration that you enable on you bios, the things that you can do is

1)Read the manual of your mother board looking for some light on dual channel configuration

2)Enter on you bios, or UEFI and see the configuration of the memory part, look for any hint on dual-channel mode